# Select Query Joined on Two Fields?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, join

I've got a few tables in an access database:

```
ID | LocationName
1  | Location1
2  | Location2

ID | LocationID | Date  | NumProductsDelivered
1  |     1      | 12/10 |      3
2  |     1      | 01/11 |      2
3  |     1      | 02/11 |      2
4  |     2      | 11/10 |      1
5  |     2      | 12/10 |      1

ID | LocationID | Date  | NumEmployees | EmployeeType
1  |     1      | 12/10 |      10      |      1 (=Permanent)
2  |     1      | 12/10 |       3      |      2 (=Temporary)
3  |     1      | 12/10 |       1      |      3 (=Support)
4  |     2      | 10/10 |       1      |      1
5  |     2      | 11/10 |       2      |      1
6  |     2      | 11/10 |       1      |      2
7  |     2      | 11/10 |       1      |      3
8  |     2      | 12/10 |       2      |      1
9  |     2      | 12/10 |       1      |      3
```

What I want to do is pass in the LocationID as a parameter and get back something like the following table. So, if I pass in 2 as my LocationID, I should get:

```
Date  | NumProductsDelivered | NumPermanentEmployees | NumSupportEmployees
10/10 |                      |           1           |           
11/10 |          1           |           2           |          1
12/10 |          1           |           2           |          1
```

It seems like this should be a pretty simple query. I really don't even need the first table except as a way to fill in the combo box on the form from which the user chooses which location they want a report for. Unfortunately, everything I've done has resulted in me getting a lot more data than I should be getting. My confusion is in how to set up the join (presumably that's what I'm looking for here) given that I want both the date and locationID to be the same for each row in the result set.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Ok - the answer below didn't quite work, but it did set me on the right track and I was able to use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.Date, t2.NumProductsDelivered, 
  (SELECT t1a.NumEmployees
    FROM table3 t1a
    WHERE t1a.EmployeeType=1 AND t1a.LocationID=t1.LocationID AND t1a.Date= t1.Date)
  AS "PermEmps", 
  (SELECT t1b.NumEmployees
    FROM table3 t1b
    WHERE t1b.EmployeeType=3 AND t1b.LocationID=t1.LocationID AND t1b.Date=t1.Date)
  AS "SupportEmps"
FROM table3 AS t1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (t2.Date=t1.Date) 
  AND (t2.LocationID=t1.LocationID)
WHERE t1.LocationID=2
GROUP BY t1.Date, t1.LocationID, t2.NumProductsDelivered;
```

This is getting me the results I was looking for. However, in a case where the location has a break between products being delivered, I don't see the correct results. It seems that the recordset stops as soon as there's an empty row and then never picks back up again. So, where I might expect to see this:

```
Date  | NumProductsDelivered | NumPermanentEmployees | NumSupportEmployees
10/10 |                      |           1           |           
11/10 |          1           |           2           |          1
12/10 |          1           |           2           |          1
01/10 |          2           |                       |          1
06/10 |          1           |                       |
```

I only see this:

```
Date  | NumProductsDelivered | NumPermanentEmployees | NumSupportEmployees
10/10 |                      |           1           |           
11/10 |          1           |           2           |          1
12/10 |          1           |           2           |          1
01/10 |          2           |                       |          1
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to GROUP BY t1.LocationID since you're not selecting it and it is always 2.  I would also recommend using better names than "t1" for readability.  The other problem is a mystery... Do you have a 1-to-1 relationship between t1 and t2?  Also, try taking out the join and subselects to see if you get all the dates you need (I'll add to my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

**[deleted original]**

Try this instead (untested):

```
select t3.date, t2.numproductsdelivered, 
  (select sum(t3.numemployees)
   from table3 t3a
   where t3a.locationid = t3.locationid and t3a.date = t3.date and t3a.employeetype = 1
  ) as numpermanentemployees,
  (select sum(t3.numemployees)
   from table3 t3b
   where t3b.locationid = t3.locationid and t3b.date = t3.date and t3b.employeetype = 3
  ) as numsupportemployees
from table3 as t3
left join table2 as t2 on t2.locationid = t3.locationid and t2.date = t3.date
where t3.locationid = 2
group by t3.date, t2.numproductsdelivered
```

If you didn't mind having separate rows for each employee type it could be simplified:

```
select t3.date, t2.numproductsdelivered, t3.employeetype, sum(t3.numemployees) as numemployees
from table3 as t3
left join table2 as t2 on t2.locationid = t3.locationid and t2.date = t3.date
where t3.locationid = 2 and t3.employeetype in (1, 3)
group by t3.date, t2.numproductsdelivered, t3.employeetype
```

**Edit:**  Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.Date
FROM table3 AS t1
WHERE t1.LocationID=2
GROUP BY t1.Date
```

...and see if you get all the dates.

Then add the left join:

```
SELECT t1.Date, t2.NumProductsDelivered
FROM table3 AS t1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (t2.Date=t1.Date) 
  AND (t2.LocationID=t1.LocationID)
WHERE t1.LocationID=2
GROUP BY t1.Date, t1.LocationID, t2.NumProductsDelivered;
```

If it's doing a left INNER join, then it will remove rows from t1 that don't have a matching row in t2.  Try explicitly setting a left OUTER join and see if that works.  The RDBMS I've used the most defaults to outer, but maybe yours (Access) defaults to inner.

So I am thinking the following will work (add "OUTER" and remove "t1.LocationId"):

```
SELECT t1.Date, t2.NumProductsDelivered, 
  (SELECT t1a.NumEmployees
    FROM table3 t1a
    WHERE t1a.EmployeeType=1 AND t1a.LocationID=t1.LocationID AND t1a.Date= t1.Date)
  AS "PermEmps", 
  (SELECT t1b.NumEmployees
    FROM table3 t1b
    WHERE t1b.EmployeeType=3 AND t1b.LocationID=t1.LocationID AND t1b.Date=t1.Date)
  AS "SupportEmps"
FROM table3 AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (t2.Date=t1.Date) 
  AND (t2.LocationID=t1.LocationID)
WHERE t1.LocationID=2
GROUP BY t1.Date, t2.NumProductsDelivered;
```

Comment: A couple of notes:

1. I had to switch the 'group by' and 'where' parts of the query or Acccess wouldn't even let me save it.
2. Upon trying to run it, I'm getting an error:

You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'numproductsdelivered' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: Yeah, you can't select anything you didn't group by (except for agreggated values)...  In this case I think you can simply change to group by t3.date, t2.numproductsdelivered, since that additional grouping won't change the results (you only have one numproductsdelivered in each date).  I fixed my answer (maybe not completely)

Comment: That still didn't quite work, but it helped lead me to an answer that seems to be working except in one case (see above).

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
DECLARE @LocationId int

SET @LocationId=2

SELECT L2.LocationId, L2.Date, COUNT(DISTINCT NumProductsDelivered) as NumProductsDelivered,
 SUM(case when L2.EmployeeType =1 then NumEmployees else 0 end) as NumPermanentEmployees,
 SUM(case when L2.EmployeeType =3 then NumEmployees else 0 end) as NumSupportEmployees
FROM L1 
    RIGHT JOIN L2
        ON L1.LocationID=L2.LocationID
        AND L1.Date=L2.Date
WHERE L2.LocationId=@LocationId
GROUP BY L2.LocationId, L2.Date
```

Comment: What stood out is "case"... Why didn't I think of that?? :)  Not sure if the rest works...

Comment: This is a T-SQL answer for a question about an Access/Jet/ACE database (I see no mention of SQL Server in the question itself or in the tags). -1 for not paying attention and providing a non-working answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I did not see it was about Access, my mistake. With Access instead of CASE you should use IIF to achieve the same result.